# Calculator History: Adding to an array

Tags: c#, list, winforms, calculator, streamwriter

I need to create a calculator history for a calculator I am developing in C#.

From OperateBLL.cs I am passing an object and the operators/results to a method in HistoryDAL.cs called WriteHistory, from here I am using SteamWriter to connect to a text file call history.txt.

What I would like to do is add each operation to a List and then proceed to save each element of the List into the text file which will be called in Form1.cs and shown in the TextBox tb_operations.

All I am managing to do at the moment is keep overwriting the same entry at index 0 of the List, I am unsure on how to keep adding each set of operations to the array and proceed to write them to the text file.

History.Dal.cs

```
public void writeHistory(CalculoVO yeah, string operator, double resul)
{
    StreamWriter escribir = new StreamWriter("history.txt");

    List<string> history = new List<string>();

    history.Add(yeah.Num2.ToString() + " " + operador + " " + yeah.Num1.ToString() + " = " + result);
  

     foreach (var entry in history) {

         escribir.WriteLine(entry);

     }

    escribir.Close();
}
```

OperarBLL.cs (I pass the parameters from here to the method in HistoryDAL.cs)

```
controladorDAL.writeHistory(sumaObjeto, "*", resultado);
```

Form1.cs (It writes to the textbox fine)

```
private void readHistory()
{
    string path = "historial.txt";

    string[] readHist = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    foreach (string s in readHist)
    {
        tb_historial.Text = s;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `writeHistory`you create new List in the line:

```
List<string> history = new List<string>();
```

`history` have to be defined / created outside of `writeHistory`. It could be defined as a field in the class containing method `writeHistory`, then you will have access from the method to the field.

```cs
public class A
{
  List<string> history = new List<string>();

  public void writeHistory(CalculoVO yeah, string Operator, double result)
  {
    StreamWriter escribir = new StreamWriter("history.txt", true);
    history.Add(yeah.Num2.ToString() + " " + Operator + " " + eah.Num1.ToString() + " = " + result);
    // ....
   }
}
```

Other possibility is create `history` in another object and pass it to `writeHistory` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. If I do it this way, declarng the Array in the historyDAL class as far as I can see it is still overwriting the first index each instead of adding them.

Comment: It is simmilar problem, with `StreamWriter escribir = new StreamWriter("history.txt");` you overwrite "history.txt" each time you call `writeHistory`. Using other `StreamWriter` constructor you could append data to the file - see [public StreamWriter (string path, bool append);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_)